# open iphone settings via phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova, settings

Can you help me, how to open iphone settings via phonegap.
I've tried test but there is nothing.

I'm working on Xcode 4.3, iOS sdk 5.1, cordova 1.7

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible as it's not possible from native applications in SDK 5.1

Comment: Apple removed the App Settings URL scheme in 5.1, they where only present in 5.0

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 8 is possible to open application settings dialog.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32229649/3340702