# iOS 9: Deeplink to iCloud Settings

Tags: ios, icloud, deep-linking

Here is my problem: I am working on an app that uses CloudKit.  I need to hand the scenario that the user is not logged in to iCloud on the device.  I would like to send them to the iCloud settings, and remind them that iCloud data needs to be turned on for my app.  I am using       `NSFileManager.defaultManager().ubiquityIdentityToken` to decide if I need to open the user's iCloud settings.  **The problem is, I can't figure out how**.  What is the URL for the device's iCloud settings?  I have done a lot of research, and know I do not want `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`.  This open's the app's settings, not the devices.  This is not made any easier with iOS 9's new security features, which I think I have set up properly:

[image]

Comment: Looks like this already has an answer here (it's not possible) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988241/url-scheme-open-settings-ios

Comment: You can't open the Settings app other than for your own app's settings. And `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` has nothing at all to do with this.

Comment: I was under the impression that    LSApplicationQueriesSchemes    is a way to whitelist URLs that have been blocked by default for security in iOS 9

Comment: It's the list of URL schemes that you wish to use with calls to `UIApplication canOpenURL:`. What does that have to do with your question?

Comment: I thought I could open settings with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch iCloud section of the Settings App. I have tested this both on **iOS 9.3 and 10.2**.

The steps are as follows:

1. Add a new URL Scheme to your app from the Project Settings/Info/URL Types.

[image]

2. Now, you can open Settings/iCloud app with this code.

   ```
   let iCloudURL = URL(string: "App-prefs:root=CASTLE")
   if let settingsURL = iCloudURL {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsURL)
   }
   ```

Note for iOS 10.*: `openURL` method is actually deprecated and you should use the open with completion handler method:

```
open(_ url: URL, 
     options: [String : Any] = [:], 
     completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

*References*

- [Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42915/complete-documentation-of-the-ios-settings-apps-url-scheme

Comment: I just had an app rejected for using `App-prefs:root`. "Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change."

Comment: when I code let iCloudURL = URL(string: "App-prefs:root=CASTLE") it brings me to the general settings widndow :/