# Is there a way to access and modify iOS settings with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, settings

Are there any classes or frameworks out there that allow my app to access and modify iPhone settings of the device used to visit my app? I know there's plenty of apps out there which (for example) can change the screen brightness of the device, so I was wondering if it's also possible to modify other settings you can manage in the Settings app on your device (i.e. automatic device lock, time and date, etc.).

Comment: I think the best bet is to send them there via a [URL scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26890325/1305067).

Comment: @paulvs Nah, that would open the actual Settings app. I know how to do that, that's not very difficult. What I want to do, is let users control device settings from my app. For example, add a button to my app which changes the iPhone home screen background when tapped. So I'm only looking for the code to manipulate device settings without having the user access the Settings app. I've just been Googling some stuff, and Im pretty sure the UIKit Framework won't allow this, but Im kinda hoping there's a third-party custom framework out there to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: No settings are available to 3rd party apps.

Comment: @rmaddy 
https://appsto.re/nl/3x8mF.i pretty sure this one has access to my device settings

Answer (score 2):

No this can't be done... What you can do is to open the settings and that's it. Apple does not allow you to change anything outside your application.