# Open phone settings when button is clicked in my app

Tags: swift3, ios10, emoji, custom-keyboard

I recently upgraded to Xcode 8 and converted my code to Swift 3. I am making a custom keyboard (extension) which worked perfectly fine till iOS 9, but i am facing a couple of issues in iOS 10.

1. The container app of the custom keyboard contains a button which directs the user to the keyboard settings to add the keyboard

**Issue: This button click is not working in iOS 10 i.e the user is not directed to the settings. I have configured the URL Schemes in my project and have tried the following code :**

```
@IBAction func btnGetStarted(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
    if let url = settingsUrl {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Also tried :

```
@IBAction func btnGetStarted(_ sender: AnyObject) {

if let settingsURL = URL(string:"prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/KEYBOARDS") {
 UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsURL)
 }
}
```

2. The custom keyboard also contains emoji images. The user requires to enable "Allow Access" in the settings to use the emoji images. If the user does not enable "Allow access" then he cannot use the emoji images. If the "Allow access" is not enable and the user tries to click the emoji a toast pops up which tells the user to go to settings and enable "Allow access".

**Issue: This toast does not pop up when the app is run in iOS 10**

Code of the toast:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    let pbWrapped: UIPasteboard? = UIPasteboard.general

    if let pb = pbWrapped {
        if  currentKeyboard == XXXXXX.emoji {
            if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(dataEmoji[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]) {
                pb.setData(data, forPasteboardType: "public.png")

                  self.makeToast(pasteMessage, duration: 3.0, position: .center)
            }
        }

    } else {
        var style = ToastStyle()
        style.messageColor = UIColor.red
        style.messageAlignment = .center
        //style.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        self.makeToast("To really enjoy the keyboard, please Allow Full Access in the settings application.", duration: 8.0, position: .center, title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "toast.png"), style: style, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I did check out few solutions on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me, as I said before my app works perfectly fine on all versions except iOS 10.
Please can someone help me out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152526/how-do-i-open-phone-settings-when-a-button-is-clicked-ios

Comment: @Rock As i have written above i have already tried that, dint work for me

Comment: @PersianBlue: Have you got the answer, I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Raj_216 No i havn't found a solution yet..

Comment: @PersianBlue: Ok, I will post solution once I get it & if you find it before me then please do the same.

Comment: Have you tried to force close the Settings App before using the openURL within your app? Seems like the settings app can get in a state where it can't load the resource whilst already open so shows a white screen.

Comment: @svarrall Oh i dint know that, so haven't tried. Could please guide me how do i go about it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Swift 3 iOS 10**

```
let settingsUrl = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) as! URL
UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: i had tried this as well, but it just directs me to a blank screen

Comment: it's looks like you forgot about Request user permission in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. check it

Comment: I added the URL Types in the settings as follows - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35542855/6077720. Then what is the need for user permission in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: Because it is swift 3, I believe you should be doing `URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!` instead of doing NSURL -> URL case

Answer (score 3):

@persianBlue: This is working on Xcode8 + iOS10.

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

Comment: I have already tried this. This directs the app to the phone settings app but its only a white screen and before the settings options are displayed the app closes

Comment: Looks like some people are not affected by the crash. I'm facing the same crash from the day I updated to iOS 10. Even updating to iOS 10.0.2 didn't resolve it.

Comment: Just for reference the crash log is here: http://pastebin.com/L9zQ7kmZ. Hopefully someone will be able to extract what's actually happening.

Comment: openURL(url: URL)  is deprecated in Swift 3.
You'll need to use open(url:, options, completionHandler:)

Comment: @PeterJohnson It was deprecated in iOS 10, but if you're targeting anything less than iOS 10, you'll need to continue using `openUrl`

Answer (score 1):

`UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` provides a link to the app's settings. Previous to iOS10, if the app lacked a settings.Bundle, it would link to the settings home page. The logs would show:

`_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)`

If your intention is to link to the app's settings, you simply need to add a settings bundle. [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW6)

I have yet to find a way to link to the phone's setting's Home page.

Comment: Did you find a way to link the phones settings?

Answer (score 1):

This is no possible in iOS11 anymore, we can just open Settings like:

```
if let url = URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
   //iOS 10 +
   UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:{ didOpen in
      print("Opened \(didOpen)") 
   })
   //iOS 9 +
   UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see a white screen just like @PersianBlue your app might be missing custom settings. 
Here's what the documentation has to say about `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`:

> Used to create a URL that you can pass to the openURL(_:) method. When
>   you open the URL built from this string, the system launches the
>   Settings app and displays the app’s custom settings, if it has any.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the below function, it worked for me. I help it will help you guys.

`func openLocationSettings(){
        let scheme:String = UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString
        if let url = URL(string: scheme) {
            if #available(iOS 10, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],
                                          completionHandler: {
                                            (success) in
                                            print("Open \(scheme): \(success)")
                })
            } else {
                let success = UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                print("Open \(scheme): \(success)")
            }
        }
    }`