# How to use core bluetooth framework to connect Headsets/handsfree?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am working on an iOS core Bluetooth application,but i dont know how to communication with the device.I want to initiate a **pairing mechanism** when a central send a request to connect.

i also see this article https://invasivecode.com/weblog/core-bluetooth-for-ios-6-core-bluetooth-was/ but i dont understand how to **scanning and pairing mechanism**.

can some one help me? thank you

Comment: @BenN My question is using core bluetooth to scanning and pairing mechanism for any devices like handset,any android device or any bluetooth accessories etc.

Comment: Core Bluetooth can only be used to connect with Bluetooth Low Energy devices.  Headsets/handsfree devices are typically Bluetooth 2.1 devices which are not supported under Core Bluetooth.  Can you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve, what you have attempted and the problems you are having?  Have you read the Core Bluetooth Programming Guide?

Comment: @Paulw11 My first target is connect to  **Headsets/handsfree**  but no idea how to connect or how to that functionality implement  and also core Bluetooth to try to connect iOS to iOS  but not show **available device** list .

Comment: To connect to headsets/handsets you use the settings app on the phone.  You can't do it through your own app.  To use Core Bluetooth between two iOS devices you need to have your app running on both devices - one acts as a peripheral, the other as a central

Comment: @Paulw11 if any possibility  to open setting page in the app and it allow to apple ?

Comment: No.  You can now open your own apps setting page, but not any other settings

Comment: @Paulw11 own apps setting page show the bluetooth  and how to open own apps setting page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824054/how-to-open-settings-programmatically-like-in-facebook-app