# iOS how to programmatically launch WIFI page from Settings App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my iOS application, I'd like to make a method 
that opens/launches the **Settings Application**,
**>> particularly the WIFI *page*, where you pick a wifi SSID <<**.

I know it is possible to open Settings App. 
cf [How to open Settings programmatically like in Facebook app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824054/how-to-open-settings-programmatically-like-in-facebook-app)

Is it possible to land on the Wifi *page* of it?
If yes, how?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort

Comment: It is not possible to do that. You can find more information here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824054/how-to-open-settings-programmatically-like-in-facebook-app

Comment: @ryancrunchi Sorry, I ve forgotten a detail, which I have not found anything very informative . I aim to open the **wifi page** of settings app... and get back to the app at any moment.

Comment: Ok, then it should be even more impossible than showing settings home page :)

Comment: @ryancrunchi since iOS8 you can open settings home page. Should or not, probability ? I'm hoping binary sure answer... it is or not. It should... ahah ;) well, Im digging it, I come back soon with a formal YES or NO. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, using the UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString you can get the URL used to open the Settings app.

Because this is iOS 8 only, on iOS 7 or earlier you will need to check this exists before using it (or your app will crash)

```
   if(&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != nil)
  {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
  }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you. Actually I'm looking for landing on the Wifi page of Settings App.

Comment: 3pic, did you ever find that specific answer?

Comment: As of iOS 8 you can only launch your app's own settings page. (But can't access in specific like wifi page in setting) as per apple API