# Is there a way to go to "Settings" in URL schemes?

Tags: ios, xcode, settings

I want to know if there is a way to open "Settings" of the device, where are Wifi Toggler, Data Toggler, Air Plane Toggler...

I have a shortcut to "prefs:root=WIFI", but I don't know If I can open this WIFI settings and simulate a click on a back button to go to Settings.

I'm developing on iOS 7 and greater.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app

Comment: This is to open the settings of the app, not of the phone.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824054/how-to-open-settings-programmatically-like-in-facebook-app  answer by **richard-venable**

Comment: Thank you @saurabh-prajapati, bad lucky this time.

Comment: you're welcome! is it solved your problem ?? so that i can post this as an answer! as it will helps other too.

Answer (score 1):

As I just read, this is not possible. Answered by @richard-venable in [**How to open Settings programmatically like in Facebook app?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824054/how-to-open-settings-programmatically-like-in-facebook-app).

- **There is no URL you can use to get to the root level of the Settings app.**
- You can send the user to your app's section of the Settings app using UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString in iOS 8.

Thanks to @[saurabh-prajapati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3913934/saurabh-prajapati) for the comment.