# How to open Facebook app settings from another App IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have the code to open my app settings:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

But how do i get it to open Facebook app settings instead of mine ?.

Comment: I want to know how too because facebook login fails when the user disables your app from facebook under Facebook's settings

Answer (score 2):

for reference purpose I Taken the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824054/how-to-open-settings-programmatically-like-in-facebook-app)

> If your app has it’s own settings bundle, the settings will be opened showing your app’s settings. If your app does not have a setting bundle, the main settings page will be shown.

```
if(&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != nil)
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
}
```

**Swift**

```
if UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != nil {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
 }
```

Comment: How would i edit this to open Facebooks App Settings instead of mine?

Comment: doesnt ans the op's qns

Comment: i agree. i want to open the facebook settings because someone said 'dont allow app xyz access to log me in through facebook'. if they change their mind later, they won't know how to find facebook settings > allow my app xyz