# The "prefs" URL Scheme is not working in iOS 10 (Beta 1 & 2)

Tags: swift, url-scheme, ios10

I can't get the "prefs" URL Scheme to work in iOS 10 (Beta 1). 
It's set up correctly since the same App works fine on iOS 9.

Is this a bug or did it get renamed / removed?

Code:

```
let settingsUrl = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=SOMETHING")
if let url = settingsUrl {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

**Update:** *(Beta 2)* 
Still not working in Beta 2. 
It seams to be an bug. For example if you want do invite someone using GameCenter in iOS 10 and you're not logged into iMessage, you'll get a popup asking you to log in. But the "Settings" button does absolutely nothing.

Comment: You probably need `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` which been available since iOS9

Comment: Are URL-Schemes removed in iOS 10? Can't find any release notes about that.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Do you know the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes for the iOS Settings App by any chance?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just replace `prefs` to `App-Prefs` for iOS 10

Below code works for iOS 8,9,10

Swift 3.0 and Xcode >= 8.1

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
{
       UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=SOMETHING")!)
}
else
{
       UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "prefs:root=SOMETHING")!)
}
```

Swift 2.2

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
{
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"App-Prefs:root=SOMETHING")!)
}
else
{        
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"prefs:root=SOMETHING")!)
}
```

Works for me.

Happy Coding

Comment: Hello Saumil  , First all of thank you for answer , i tried your code for "LOCATION_SERVICES" but app will navigate me to setting page not direct to enable location service page

Comment: I'll check and let you know

Comment: Just guessed the new scheme:  ``App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION``

Comment: Yes, It should be work for Location `App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION`

Comment: seam that App-Prefs:root=SOMETHING is also for ios 9

Comment: It might be [rejected during app review](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51093121/419348).

Comment: If we use App-Prefs:root or prefs:root then app will get rejected by Apple. Instead we should use UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString

Answer (score 5):

You can use `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` to open *your own* app's settings (this has been available since iOS 8) but any other `prefs:` URL is now considered a private API and use will result in app rejection.

Comment: Do you have a source link?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582888/when-i-was-in-use-prefs-root-wifi-by-apple-refused-to-act for one example. There are quite a few other questions here where the apps have been rejected for using it

Comment: That sucks. Is there any other way to open any other Settings page than UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Prefs:root=SOMETHING`

iOS 10 updated URL Scheme for Settings, you need to upcase the "p".

Ref: https://github.com/cyanzhong/app-tutorials/blob/master/schemes.md

**NOTICE:** It only works on Widgets, not works in Apps. (iOS 10.0.2)

@Saumil Shah's solution works in App, is more useful.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, for Location services `App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION` worked for me. When I tested on a device and not a simulator.

I won't list the things I tried that did not work, it's a long list.

Usage example that assumes either location services are disabled or permission is denied or not determined:

```
if !CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    if let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION") {
        // If general location settings are disabled then open general location settings
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
} else {
    if let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
        // If general location settings are enabled then open location settings for the app
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not available on iOS 11, we can just open Settings like:

```
if let url = URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
   if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
     UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested in a "gray area" API, you can use:

```
//url = "prefs:root=SOMETHING"
[[LSApplicationWorkspace defaultWorkspace] openSensitiveURL:url withOptions:nil];
```

This will give you what you want. **Hide it well**, and it works in iOS 10.

Comment: May I ask how to hide?

Comment: Hiding private API is not hard. Look into the Objective C runtime and how to use it with strings. You can then construct or encode these strings as you please.

Comment: I import the LSApplicationWorkspace.h, and using your method [[LSApplicationWorkspace defaultWorkspace] openSensitiveURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"] withOptions:nil]; When I compile to ipad, it will show  <private> is currently restricted and not eligible to open the <private> scheme. log. Have you some example run on the ipad or iphone , not on the simulator ? I'm test the code on the simulator can work, but on the device is not working.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I did run on device, and it worked. It was in the latter betas. Maybe something changed in GM. I doubt it, because Apple uses this API to open various settings from their alerts.

Comment: Did you have sample code on the github? I hope I can try your code in my device. Maybe  that is my code have some fault ?! thank you

Comment: No, sorry. I did it in my previous place of work - we needed to jump to the profile settings. No longer have access to that code.

Comment: okey! thank you ~ I will still try to search other method. thanks.

Comment: strange....but "prefs:root.." links do NOT work.  while "Prefs:root..." (yes, initial capped) links DO work when doing this. in iOS 10.