# can not jump to the system settings page

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10

When I click on the About page in the settings, an error message is displayed:

```
2016-11-25 19:49:04.352 ass176[4729:186745] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "prefs:root=General&path=About" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

This is the code:

```
let url = URL(string: "prefs:root=General&path=About")

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!){
     UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Environment: iOS 10.1, XCode 8.1

[image]

Comment: Opening prefs URLs aside from your own app settings  is not permitted and will result in a rejection for private API use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's not permitted anymore. You'll have to use `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` for your own app settings.

You can read @Paulw11 answer here:
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38588089/5620628)

Answer (score 0):

Error code 10814 tells that.

```
No application in the Launch Services database matches the input criteria.
```

You can get it by [link](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-10814)

The solution i prefer is Try Reset the simulator. And re-run the project.