# Url scheme in ios10

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, ios10

I am try to open account setting using "prefs:root=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS" in ios9 it is working fine. But in ios10. I get this error.
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "prefs:root=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)".
I google this and found "prefs:root" no more. :(
I want to know is there any alternative available for "prefs:root..."

```
{
            if let phoneSettingURL:NSURL = NSURL(string:"prefs:root=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS") {
                let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
                if (application.canOpenURL(phoneSettingURL as URL)) {
                    application.openURL(phoneSettingURL as URL);
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: you can redirect to your app's setting's page by using `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` as URL string.

Comment: that may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064557/the-prefs-url-scheme-not-woring-in-ios-10-beta-1-2