# Is it possible to configure Apple Pay right from the app?

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, applepay

We are using Stripe gateway for Apple Pay integration. It provides way to check if Apple Pay configured on device, but I'm curious if it is possible to show a kind of system dialog asking to configure Apple Pay. Opening system preferences (ex. [How to open Settings programmatically like in Facebook app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824054/how-to-open-settings-programmatically-like-in-facebook-app)) will also do, though I'm not sure if it's the allowed approach, and the app will not be banned by Apple.

Thanks.

Comment: [PKAddPaymentPassViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/passkit/pkaddpaymentpassviewcontroller)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try it.

Comment: You don't want that class. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PKAddPaymentPassController` is intended for banks who want to add their own cards directly to Apple Pay. You won't be able to use it for what you're intending.

Instead you should use `PKPassLibrary -openPaymentSetup`, which will allow you to open the Apple Pay setup flow (either in Wallet on iPhone, or Settings on iPad).

Comment: Thanks for response, will check it.