# How To Enable iCloud Music Library Through Objective-C

Tags: icloud, apple-music

Is there a way to enable the iCloud Music Library through code in such a way that it calls the same functions that are called when a user tries adding a song to their playlist in Apple Music if they do not have iCloud Music Library enabled?

Just to add a bit of clarity, what I want is the same iOS Native popups that the user sees when they go to their settings and try to enable iCloud Music Library which is also called and displayed when they try to add a song to their playlist in the Apple Music App.

It's this one

https://cdn2.macworld.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3630990/2_turn_off.jpg

but instead of asking them to disable iCloud Music Library it asks them to enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no such API** now to do this.
You can only show alert to user and [send him to Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824054/how-to-open-settings-programmatically-like-in-facebook-app/23824117).

Comment: Can you reference such documentation?